# How to copy the whole database to another server database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am currently working on a Windows application with a MySQL backend.
Now I want to copy the old database structure and data to a new database server.

How can I solve this problem using MySQL workbench?

Thank you!

Comment: i tried using SQL YOG trial version but it not copies the rows completely

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. Open MySQL Workbench
2. Create the old server's connection (if you haven't it)
3. Create the new server's connection (if you haven't it)
4. Go to Server Administration and click Manage Import / Export
5. Select old server
6. Select all schemas in Export to Disk tab
7. In options select Export to Self-Contained File, wait until it finished
8. Back to Server Administration and click Manage Import / Export
9. Select new server
10. Switch to "Import from Disk"
11. Click "import from Self-contained File

This is the way with only MySQL Workbech, some times you haven't it installed in new server, like in development to production scenario, in this way you should execute the mysqlimport utility.

Comment: **Export to Self-Contained File** doesn't work for me (I'm using Workbench 6.0). Luckily **Export to Dump Project Folder** works fine!

Answer (score 12):

**Using MySQL Workbench [Migration Wizard]**

To directly copy a database from one server to another (even a local one) without creating intermediary export/dump files, you can do so within MySQL Workbench using its [Migration Wizard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration.html).  Go to `Database` --> `Migration Wizard`.

From there you can select the source and destination connections if you've previously saved them to your Connections list, or you can create  a new connection on the fly (be sure to check the box add it to your Connections list).
You'll also choose the database type, or select their generic version (don't remember what it's called) and let it figure out what kind of database servers you have.  Generally you can select MySQL for either MySQL or MariaDB databases, as MariaDB is generally designed to be a "binary drop-in replacement" to MySQL.

When it asks you to select which databases, it's my understanding that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is read only, and should not be selected.  Otherwise, unless you have specific needs, probably select all the other tables, if you are, say, cloning the server (and perhaps its related website).

From there you'll let MySQL Workbench do its thing.  Keep clicking next while it goes through the process of reverse engineering your schema from the old to the new servers, until it finally copies the data over.

There are many points where you can make changes before proceeding.  Also you have the option of viewing potential issues and warnings it notes during the process.

When it's done, you'll still need to add users (manually?) for the cloned database.  There is probably an automated way to clone the users table over as well, but I don't know about it.  You can do this from the command line if nothing else.  Since I use this for my local dev, I only have myself to add anyway.

I'm not sure it's any faster using this tool than exporting and importing the databases in the usual manner.  But it's sure easier.
This tool is actually designed for more complex migrations between differing kinds of databases (eg PostgressSQL and MySQL) rather than as a general tool for, say, retrieving a copy of your live database down to your local dev server or vice versa.

Under the same menu, there is `Database` -> `Schema Transfer Wizard`, which I understood to be used when you need to update to a new server version.  I'm not clear specifically the differences between the two tools, or their actual use cases.

Instructions on how to do standard Import / Export operations, in MySQL workbench, the docs are [SQL Data Export and Import Wizard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html), and [Table Data Export and Import Wizard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html).

It would be cool if it were possible to directly import / export between dev and live servers, simply by choosing Connections, rather than saving then reading in dump files.
I think it can be done via the command line though.

Comment: Here are links on how to export/import the database users: https://serverfault.com/questions/8860/how-can-i-export-the-privileges-from-mysql-and-then-import-to-a-new-server and https://serverfault.com/questions/36660/how-can-i-copy-mysql-users-table-from-one-server-to-another

Comment: Also here is a link on how to transfer a database between 2 servers from the command line: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-between-two-servers

Answer (score 7):

To copy a database directly, without doing an export and import first, you can use the [*MySQL Utilities*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-utilities.html) command [`mysqldbcopy`](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-utilities-1.5-en.a4.pdf):

```
mysqldbcopy --source=root:root@localhost --destination=root:root@localhost world:world_clone
```

You can either run the command in a Windows `cmd` or the *MySQL Utilities Console*.

Comment: Here is the link to download mysql-utilities: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/utilities/.  MySQL recommends transitioning over to MySQL Shell, however, which is here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/

Answer (score 1):

If you installed **phpmyadmin**, you can use following steps:

1. In the **phpmyadmin** of source server, using the "**Export**" function, make sure

a) In the Export Method, choose **"Custom - display all possible options"**

b) In the "Format-specific options", make sure "structure and data " are selected.

c) In the **"Object creation options"**, make sure " **ADD CREATE DATABASE / USE statement** " also marked.

Export the SQL file.

1. **scp** the exported file from the source server to the target server
2. In the phpmyadmin of the target server, using the "**Import**" function, import the SQL file to the database. There was no custom option need to select during the import process.

Comment: Not related to question MySQL Workbench, but still a helpful option if installed

Answer (score 0):

if both of your mysql servers are running in a linux environments (there is a high chance for that even if your application is for windows), the most reliable & fast way to copy a database would be by running this oneliner on a server we copy to:

```
ssh -p <ssh port (usually 22)> host.from.where.we.copy "mysqldump -u my.sql.username.on.from.host -p\"mysql.password (might require some escaping-magic in case you got special characters in there)\" -F -f --databases name.of.database.we.copy | grep -vE \"^(USE|CREATE DATABASE)\" | bzip2 -c -" </dev/null > /tmp/name.of.database.we.copy.sql.bz2; bzip2 -dc /tmp/name.of.database.we.copy.sql.bz2 | mysql -u mysql.username.on.host.we.copy.to -p'mysql.password' new.database.name
```

For example:

```
ssh -p 22 example.com "mysqldump -u root -p\"12345\" -F -f --databases mycooldb | grep -vE \"^(USE|CREATE DATABASE)\" | bzip2 -c -" </dev/null > /tmp/mycooldb.sql.bz2; bzip2 -dc /tmp/mycooldb.sql.bz2 | mysql -u someotheruser -p'54321' mynewcooldbcopy
```

That would make a dump on a host we copying from, compress it with bz2, transfer file to the new server & deploy db to another user (if needed) and name