# mysql is not valid at this position expecting eof

Tags: mysql, heroku, eof, cleardb

```
SELECT ref,
       Sum(transactions.amount)
         OVER(
           ORDER BY id)
FROM   transactions
```

localhost mysql phpmyadmin runs the code with no problems. However when uploading to heroku ClearDB "mysql is not valid at this position expecting eof" error shows

Answer (score 0):

MySQL didn't support [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) (e.g. `SUM OVER()`) [until version 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html):

> MySQL now supports window functions that, for each row from a query, perform a calculation using rows related to that row. These include functions such as `RANK()`, `LAG()`, and `NTILE()`. In addition, several existing aggregate functions now can be used as window functions (for example, `SUM()` and `AVG()`).

But [ClearDB defaults to version 5.6 and doesn't offer anything newer than version 5.7](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#the-cleardb-dedicated-mysql-complete-tutorial-local-setup).

There are other Heroku addons that provide MySQL, though:

- JawsDB for MySQL addon [does support MySQL 8](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb#choosing-mysql-version), and currently uses that version by default
- Stackhero for MySQL [says it supports "up-to-date versions"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ah-mysql-stackhero), but doesn't have a free tier

I suggest you switch to JawsDB for MySQL. Provision the add-on, [copy your data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12472201/354577) from ClearDB to JawsDB, and point your application to JawsDB. Once you're sure everything is working you can de-provision the ClearDB database.